# Use to or Used to exercises , help me complete the sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, complements, used-to

1. When we were children, we ____________________ collect stamps.
2. Mr. Wood ______________ read at leat four hours a day when he was young.
3. John __________________ walk to school in the morning. Now he takes the bus.
4. They __________________ have lunch at fast food restaurants every Saturday.
5. In those days, everybody _________________ drink a lot of milk.
6. Don't worry about him! He ______________________ getting up early every day.
7. Whenever we came to Coventry we always ________________________ in the Central Hotel. We loved it.
8. They _________________ smoke when they were young.
9. Paul is nervous because he _____________________ speaking French in public.
10. There ___________________ be a cinema in our Town in those days.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Who has given you this exercise? _Use to_ is not appropriate for any of them!

Comment: What Kate said, plus "used to" isn't even appropriate in some of them

Comment: Unfortunately, on this site we are not homework solvers. Please tell us what your answers are and why, and we can comment on that.